# How to cache Python dependencies properly

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Python project in a Dockerfile. I want to cache dependencies, and then use that cache later, something like this:

```
RUN pip3 download -d "/pth/to/downloaded/files" -r /temp/requirements.txt -c /temp/constraints.txt

# much later on in the Dockerfile:

RUN pip3 install --download-cache="/pth/to/downloaded/files" -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
```

---

**Question**: 
Assuming the `pip3 download` command is correct, I no longer see a `--download-cache` option when I look at the `pip3 --help` output - is there a new option I can use with `pip3 install` to reference the dependency cache generated by `pip3 download`?

Right now I am getting this error:

> Usage:      pip install [options]
>
> no such option: --download-cache

Comment: I'm not sure (so not adding it as an answer now), but there's an option `--cache-dir <dir>` which might be what you're looking for. Alternatively, there also seems to be an environment variable $PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE which you can set. PS: Nice trick to download the packages in a separate Docker layer :-)

Comment: I just installed Docker to do some tests, and found the solution. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56226847/10669875) below.

Answer (score 8):

The `--download-cache` option was removed in pip version 8, because it's now using cache by default. So you don't need to specify this option at all. I'm not sure what the purpose of the `pip download -d <dir>` option is, but apparently it's not creating a cache in the destination directory. You can just leave out the `-d <dir>` option too. The following Dockerfile works:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY constraints.txt requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 download -d .pipcache -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
COPY test.txt ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
```

If you add `--cache-dir <dir>` to **both** the `download` and `install` commands, it will work as well. So the following Dockerfile also works:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY constraints.txt requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 download --cache-dir ./tmp/pipcache -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
COPY test.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --cache-dir ./tmp/pipcache -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
```

Example output (with only `pep8` and `pylint` in the `requirements.txt`):

First run:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> a4cc999cf2aa
Step 2/5 : COPY constraints.txt requirements.txt ./
 ---> 411eaa3d36ff
Step 3/5 : RUN pip3 download -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
 ---> Running in 6b489df74137
Collecting pep8==1.7.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 17))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/3f/669429ce58de2c22d8d2c542752e137ec4b9885fff398d3eceb1a7f5acb4/pep8-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
  Saved /pep8-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pylint==2.3.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 22))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/c2/b3f73f4ac008bef6e75bca4992f3963b3f85942e0277237721ef1c151f0d/pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (765kB)
  Saved /pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mccabe==0.6.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 14))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/89/479dc97e18549e21354893e4ee4ef36db1d237534982482c3681ee6e7b57/mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Saved /mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid==2.2.5 (from -c constraints.txt (line 2))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/ad/7221a62a2dbce5c3b8c57fd18e1052c7331adc19b3f27f1561aa6e620db2/astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (193kB)
  Saved /astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting isort==4.3.19 (from -c constraints.txt (line 10))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/ae/5ef4b57e15489754b73dc908b656b02ab0e6d37b190ac78dd498be8b577d/isort-4.3.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
  Saved /isort-4.3.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 12))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/a5/1b19b094ad19bce55b5b6d434020f5537b424fd2b3cff0fbef23d7bb5a95/lazy_object_proxy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (49kB)
  Saved /lazy_object_proxy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting wrapt==1.11.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 39))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/b2/0f71ca90b0ade7fad27e3d20327c996c6252a2ffe88f50a95bba7434eda9/wrapt-1.11.1.tar.gz
  Saved /wrapt-1.11.1.tar.gz
Collecting six==1.12.0 (from -c constraints.txt (line 28))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Saved /six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typed-ast==1.3.5 (from -c constraints.txt (line 37))
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/9e/00918af7bdd616decb5b7ad06a9cd0a4a247d2fccaa630ab448a57e68b98/typed_ast-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (736kB)
  Saved /typed_ast-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Successfully downloaded pep8 pylint mccabe astroid isort lazy-object-proxy wrapt six typed-ast
Removing intermediate container 6b489df74137
 ---> 8ac3be432c58
Step 4/5 : COPY test.txt ./
 ---> 5cac20851967
Step 5/5 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
 ---> Running in 394847f09e9b
Collecting pep8==1.7.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 17))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/3f/669429ce58de2c22d8d2c542752e137ec4b9885fff398d3eceb1a7f5acb4/pep8-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pylint==2.3.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 22))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/c2/b3f73f4ac008bef6e75bca4992f3963b3f85942e0277237721ef1c151f0d/pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid==2.2.5 (from -c constraints.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/ad/7221a62a2dbce5c3b8c57fd18e1052c7331adc19b3f27f1561aa6e620db2/astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mccabe==0.6.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 14))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/89/479dc97e18549e21354893e4ee4ef36db1d237534982482c3681ee6e7b57/mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting isort==4.3.19 (from -c constraints.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/ae/5ef4b57e15489754b73dc908b656b02ab0e6d37b190ac78dd498be8b577d/isort-4.3.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 12))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/a5/1b19b094ad19bce55b5b6d434020f5537b424fd2b3cff0fbef23d7bb5a95/lazy_object_proxy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting six==1.12.0 (from -c constraints.txt (line 28))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wrapt==1.11.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 39))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/b2/0f71ca90b0ade7fad27e3d20327c996c6252a2ffe88f50a95bba7434eda9/wrapt-1.11.1.tar.gz
Collecting typed-ast==1.3.5 (from -c constraints.txt (line 37))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/9e/00918af7bdd616decb5b7ad06a9cd0a4a247d2fccaa630ab448a57e68b98/typed_ast-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/89/67/41/63cbf0f6ac0a6156588b9587be4db5565f8c6d8ccef98202fc
Successfully built wrapt
Installing collected packages: lazy-object-proxy, six, wrapt, typed-ast, astroid, isort, mccabe, pep8, pylint
Successfully installed astroid-2.2.5 isort-4.3.19 lazy-object-proxy-1.4.1 mccabe-0.6.1 pep8-1.7.1 pylint-2.3.1 six-1.12.0 typed-ast-1.3.5 wrapt-1.11.1
Removing intermediate container 394847f09e9b
 ---> 68e65a214a32
Successfully built 68e65a214a32
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Second run (after changing `test.txt` to trigger a rebuild of Docker layers 4 and 5):

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> a4cc999cf2aa
Step 2/5 : COPY constraints.txt requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 411eaa3d36ff
Step 3/5 : RUN pip3 download -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8ac3be432c58
Step 4/5 : COPY test.txt ./
 ---> 7ab5814153b7
Step 5/5 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -c constraints.txt
 ---> Running in 501da787ab07
Collecting pep8==1.7.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 17))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/3f/669429ce58de2c22d8d2c542752e137ec4b9885fff398d3eceb1a7f5acb4/pep8-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pylint==2.3.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 22))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/c2/b3f73f4ac008bef6e75bca4992f3963b3f85942e0277237721ef1c151f0d/pylint-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astroid==2.2.5 (from -c constraints.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d5/ad/7221a62a2dbce5c3b8c57fd18e1052c7331adc19b3f27f1561aa6e620db2/astroid-2.2.5-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mccabe==0.6.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 14))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/89/479dc97e18549e21354893e4ee4ef36db1d237534982482c3681ee6e7b57/mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting isort==4.3.19 (from -c constraints.txt (line 10))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/ae/5ef4b57e15489754b73dc908b656b02ab0e6d37b190ac78dd498be8b577d/isort-4.3.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typed-ast==1.3.5 (from -c constraints.txt (line 37))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/9e/00918af7bdd616decb5b7ad06a9cd0a4a247d2fccaa630ab448a57e68b98/typed_ast-1.3.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting six==1.12.0 (from -c constraints.txt (line 28))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wrapt==1.11.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 39))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/b2/0f71ca90b0ade7fad27e3d20327c996c6252a2ffe88f50a95bba7434eda9/wrapt-1.11.1.tar.gz
Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1 (from -c constraints.txt (line 12))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/a5/1b19b094ad19bce55b5b6d434020f5537b424fd2b3cff0fbef23d7bb5a95/lazy_object_proxy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: wrapt
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for wrapt (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/89/67/41/63cbf0f6ac0a6156588b9587be4db5565f8c6d8ccef98202fc
Successfully built wrapt
Installing collected packages: typed-ast, six, wrapt, lazy-object-proxy, astroid, isort, mccabe, pep8, pylint
Successfully installed astroid-2.2.5 isort-4.3.19 lazy-object-proxy-1.4.1 mccabe-0.6.1 pep8-1.7.1 pylint-2.3.1 six-1.12.0 typed-ast-1.3.5 wrapt-1.11.1
Removing intermediate container 501da787ab07
 ---> b377fe561e97
Successfully built b377fe561e97
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

NB: The [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/) was quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

As *wovano* already mentioned, as of [PIP 8.0.0](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news#id137) the `--download-cache` option was removed. `pip` uses cache by default.

To reuse the downloaded/cached packages, you can use the following strategy:

1. Download the packages to a custom destination dir, using `--dest` [as described here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/#cmdoption-d).

```sh
$ pip3 download --dest "$DEST_DIR" ...
```

2. Install the previously downloaded packages from local directory `$DEST_DIR`, using `--find-links` [as described here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-f).

```sh
$ pip3 install --find-links "file://${DEST_DIR}" ...
```

Wrapping up:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE "/var/custom-pip-download-dir"

COPY requirements1.txt ./requirements1.txt
RUN pip3 download -r requirements1.txt --dest "$PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE"

COPY requirements2.txt ./requirements2.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements2.txt --find-links "file://${PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE}"
```

Answer (score 1):

(pip maintainer here)

With modern pip versions (> 6.0), pip automatically caches the packages that it is installing if the default cache directory is accessible (see [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching)).

As long as you can somehow re-populate this cache, pip will use them when it can (though it does not fall back to it when the network availability is poor).

---

The other option (which I would personally prefer) is to download the files using pip download in one step, such that Docker can cache things on it's own. The next stage would be doing an "offline" install using `pip install --no-index` and `--find-links`.

```
$ pip download --dest=downloaded-packages project
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=downloaded-packages project
```

---

edit:

The Python Packaging User Guide, contains a guide on this too. It has a similar suggestion (though it suggests using pip wheel instead of pip download, which is a good suggestion): https://packaging.python.org/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/#caching-with-pip

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, and for the additional [link](https://packaging.python.org/guides/index-mirrors-and-caches/). However, I still don't fully understand it. (1) What do you mean with "though it does not fall back to it when the netwerk availability is poor"? If a package is already in cache, the network wouldn't be necessary, right? (2) Could you be so kind to explain the difference between using `pip download`, `pip download --dest=<dir>` and `pip wheel`. To me, this seems like three different commands with the same effect. What would be the use cases of these three commands?

Comment: Someone has to implement behavior in pip to use the cache if it doesn't have network connection. It falls back to the cache for certain files but still checks if they are out of date from PyPI. `pip download` will download the source code or "wheels" for packages. `pip wheel` will do the same and then build wheels for packages that don't have them. `--dest=<dir>` is just a way to download to a different directory (instead of the current directory).

Answer (score -1):

Caching python dependency properly means whenever building the Dockerfile it re-uses the install python dependency. I tried to build docker via using below DockerFile.

requirements.txt

```
Django==2.1.7
```

DockerFile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ADD requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Build docker image

```sh
docker build .
```

Building docker first time

### [image: building docker first time]

Building docker second time. It uses the dependency from the cache by default.

### [image]

If you make any changes or library version changes to requirements.txt then it doesn't use caching. And install the fresh library version.

Thanks.

Comment: What if step 3 is modified? Or another step is added before step 4? Then the `pip3 install` step is rerun, and it will download the Python modules again, right? I think the intent of the OP was that the downloads occur in an early layer, which will be kept cached by Docker, such that the cached Python modules will be used when rebuilding later Docker layers. Does your solution accomplish that? Unfortunately I'm not able to test it myself at the moment, but I'm interested in the solution too :-)

Comment: @wovano yes that's right, basically I am looking to get `pip download` to play along with `pip install`, where the `download` command can cache the deps