# Docker is not using cached layer

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm noticing that occassionally docker is not re-using the layer where I do a pip install of my requirements.txt

Machine info

MacOS Big Sur

```
uname -a
Darwin 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0
```

Here is my Dockerfile for a python project

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY pip.conf /root/.pip/pip.conf
COPY pip.txt /opt/deploy/pip.txt
RUN  pip install -r /opt/deploy/pip.txt
COPY . /opt/deploy
RUN  pip install /opt/deploy

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/opt/deploy/src/core.py"]
```

In a fresh build, it takes around 5minutes to build an image and then subsequent builds take ~1sec. But every once in a while docker decides to install all the packages. i.e.

```
RUN  pip install -r /opt/deploy/pip.txt
```

is not reused.

Why is that the case? What's changing? Do I not understand docker caching? Do I not understand pip better?

Do I have to freeze my requirements.txt?

Comment: I suppose `pip.txt` has not changed, right?

Comment: @EDG956 yes definitely not changed or else I wouldn't have this question :) like i said it works for most of my iterations. then the next day i login and try to do a build and it is back to installing all the deps

Comment: should i run docker build in debug mode next time?

Comment: It's been a while ago that I used Docker, but AFAIK, every `COPY` or `RUN` line creates a new layer. If a Docker command has been executed already on the same layer and it has been cached, it is not executed again but the cached layer will be used. The log contains all command that are exeucted (or skipped) and in which layer they are executed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56226847/10669875), which does not directly answer your question, but might be helpful background information.

Comment: alright. yes i can confirm pip.txt contents have not changed

Comment: What system are you running on? maybe that's useful to add in the question

Comment: What Docker version are you using? I've read somewhere that build kit makes smarter caching decisions, maybe you could try that

Comment: well it turns out i pin the base image FROM python:3.9. so now if there is a new tag for that version it gets picked up. i see there was an update 18 days ago https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.9/images/sha256-b7e449e11f8c466fbaf021dcc731563cb36a41321420db3cf506ba4d71d33a65?context=explore

Comment: would that affect the caching?

Comment: @ffff, if you include the docker build log in your question, we can probably answer that question...

Comment: @ffff I agree with wovano. We can't tell much without the log. If you see that every step after the FROM is built from scratch, then what you found out may very well be the reason. That should also be easy to test and to fix.

Answer (score 0):

The are only two reasons:

1. The `pip.txt` file content has changed.
2. The `pip.txt` file attributes (e.g. update timestamp) has changed.

Comment: pip.txt has definitely not changed. 2 could be the case. we use git, idk if that affects anything

Comment: did a `touch pip.txt` and built it, cache was reused

Comment: @ffff, ah that's weird. Please include the docker log in your question so we can take a look at what happened.